# Docker compose extra hosts with wildcards

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a container based on PHP:5-apache with many virtual hosts like

- account.site1.local
- account.site2.local
- account.site3.local

I can add all the vhosts with a wildcard on the apache conf. Is it possible to do something similar for the hosts file?

Comment: Are you trying to run multiple sites in the same container, or multiple containers, each one with one site?

Comment: I'm trying to run multiple sites on the same container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker sets up the `hosts` file when you run a container, so you don't want to manually edit it. Instead you can use the `add-host` option:

```
> docker run --add-host 1.local:127.0.0.1 alpine ping 1.local
PING 1.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
```

You can have multiple `add-host` options in the `run` command.

In Docker Compose the equivalent is `extra-hosts`:

```
extra_hosts:
 - "1.local:127.0.0.1"
 - "2.local:127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Can extra-hosts be used with wildcards? I have over 50 domains and growing, and it's a pain to update the docker-compose file each time

Comment: No, those options just add entries in `hosts` which doesn't allow wildcards. Maybe proxying your sites with an Nginx container is a better option?

Comment: @EltonStoneman `No, those options just add entries in hosts` → please can you explain what `hosts` actually? I checked `/etc/hosts` of host machine and inside container. And both of it don't have `IP hostname` record.